# openssl PSK cipher support

Tags: openssl, cipher-selection, ciphers

openssl version on ubuntu machine is

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
```

Following is openssl PSK cipher list :-

```
$ openssl ciphers -v 'PSK'
PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
PSK-RC4-SHA             SSLv3 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=RC4(128)  Mac=SHA1
PSK-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
```

How I can get following cipher list support in openssl to test

```
PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA256
PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA384
PSK-AES128-GCM-SHA256
PSK-AES256-GCM-SHA384

DHE-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA256
DHE-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA384
DHE-PSK-AES128-GCM-SHA256
DHE-PSK-AES256-GCM-SHA384

ECDHE-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA256
ECDHE-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA384

RSA-PSK-AES128-GCM-SHA256
RSA-PSK-AES256-GCM-SHA384
RSA-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA256
RSA-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA384
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How I can get following cipher list support in openssl to test

By using OpenSSL version 1.1.0 or higher:

```
$ openssl-1.1.0c ciphers -V 'PSK' 
0x00,0xAB - DHE-PSK-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
0x00,0xA8 - PSK-AES128-GCM-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
0x00,0xB7 - RSA-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA384 TLSv1 Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
0xC0,0x38 - ECDHE-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA384 TLSv1 Kx=ECDHEPSK Au=PSK  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
...
```